# For what values of $a>0$ does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a^{na}}{n^{2a}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

When $a=1$, we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1^n}{n^{2}}$$ which we already know converges.

When $a=2$, we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^{2n}}{n^{2\cdot2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{4^n}{n^{4}}$$ which we already know diverges. Thus, $1 \leqslant a < 2$.

My next inclination was to use the ratio test:
$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{\dfrac{a^{(n+1)a}}{(n+1)^{2a}}}{\dfrac{a^{na}}{n^{2a}}}=\dfrac{p^p\cdot n^{2p}}{(n+1)^{2p}}$$
and now I cannot see how to manipulate this fraction to find where it is less than one.

Comment: Write the fraction as $\frac{p^p}{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{2p}}$. In any case just look at it: the numerator is an exponential and the denominator is a polynomial. Exponentials with bases $> 1$ always overcome polynomials, so this series doesn't even pass the limit test unless $a^a \le 1$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't quite understand. How would you write this up as a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

- for $a>1$

$$\dfrac{a^{na}}{n^{2a}} \to \infty$$

and the series diverges.

- for $0<a<1$ by $b=\frac 1a>1$

$$\dfrac{a^{na}}{n^{2a}}=\dfrac{1}{n^{\frac2b}b^{\frac nb}}\le \left(\dfrac{1}{b^{\frac 1b}}\right)^n$$

and the series converges by comparison test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Concise and easy to understand!